# How to grab the first image from page url and display it along BOOKMARK description?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a social bookmarking website in **ASP.NET**  and in it I am displaying bookmarks which users add. I want to put the fist image of web page along with bookmarks to display to user. but I don't know how I get that .

**Update (14.09.11)**: Here's that solution I found:

```
(HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(TextBox1.Text); 
request.UserAgent = "LPU Crawler"; 
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); 
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream(); 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream); 
string httptxt = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
extractimgs(httptxt); 
foreach (string pic in pics) 
{ 
    TextBox2.Text += pic; 
    TextBox2.Text += "\n"; 
} 

private void extractimgs(string httptxt) 
{ 
    const string match=
        "(?<=img\\s+src\\=[\x27\x22])(?<Url>[^\x27\x22]*)(?=[\x27\x22])"; 
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(httptxt,match,
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
    for (int i = 0; i <= matches.Count - 1; i++) 
    { 
        Match anchorMatch = matches[i]; 
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(anchorMatch.Value)) 
        { 
            Response.Write("No Img Found"); 
        } 
        pics.Add(anchorMatch.ToString()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have any code that attempts to retrieve a website page?

Comment: na its just a simple wed page displaying bookmark url  and a table header to display the image ..which i want to retrive from the url ..

Comment: PS: It would be handy if you also included the code of the extractimgs(...) method. Its intent is clear, but might be handy for people looking for something similar.

Comment: yeah i gave tht function below in comments . I tried crawling the page and displayedit in a <td> of table along with bookmark url and details ..

Answer (score 1):

You could use the HTML agility pack.

You can download it via CodePlex:

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Or you can use NuGet:

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/HtmlAgilityPack

Using the Html Agility Pack you can easily download a web page and parse its contents.

To retrieve the URL of the first image you can use the following LINQ query:

```
var url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
var imageUrl = (from image in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(image.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                select image.Attributes["src"].Value).FirstOrDefault();
if (imageUrl != null)
{
   //...
}
```

You can use the address of the image(s) (SRC attribute) to include them in your own page or to issue a web request to download them.

Some quick code to download an image:

```
string imageUrl= 
    "http://www.example.com/logo.jpg";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Image image = Image.FromStream(response.GetResponseStream());
var extension = Path.GetExtension(url).Substring(0, 4);
image.Save(@"c:\test" + extension);
```

Comment: It's better that you include this code sample in your question by editing it (I already did it for you) or by posting an answer to your own question and marking it as "Answer" if it solved your issue.

Comment: Nevermind. I already adjusted it for your. I just have to wait until the edit is approved.

Comment: <private void extractimgs(string httptxt) { const string match="(?<=img\\s+src\\=[\x27\x22])(?<Url>[^\x27\x22]*)(?=[\x27\x22])"; MatchCollection matches=Regex.Matches(httptxt,match,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); for (int i = 0; i <= matches.Count - 1; i++) { Match anchorMatch = matches[i]; if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(anchorMatch.Value)) { Response.Write("No Img Found"); } pics.Add(anchorMatch.ToString()); } }>